# Incrementing counter in update loop?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to increment a counter variable roughly every 2 seconds in `SKScene` update (the game loop) I could use a timer variable and increment it using delta time.

```
self.incTimer = self.incTimer + self.deltaTime
if self.incTimer >= 2.0 {
    self.counter++
    self.incTimer = 0.0
}
```

I was curious if there was any other way, I looked at running multiple `SKAction`s with `waitForDuration` but (as I already knew) they all run concurrently. Is there a better/another way I might be missing?

Comment: You can try using an `NSTimer` to fire periodic actions.

Comment: Ordinarily that would be true, but this is from within the sprite kit runloop so NSTimer is not recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the repeatActionForever with sequence actions to make a repeating timer that runs a block every 2 seconds:

```
SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(2),
                       SKAction.runBlock({self.counter++})])
                            )
```

Comment: I overlooked that, you are indeed correct, much appreciated Sir.

Comment: Thats actually a nice way of doing this, just remember to kick the timer off outside the update. Once its going you can test for a certain point (ever 2 secs) and then reset inside update. Its not based on delta time, but if your not concerned with being super exact (to the millisecond) it will work well.

Comment: Maybe it is the same as using delta time as SKAction is executed within the game loop, hmm got me thinking now.